# Python different output when casting the recursive call with str function

Tags: python, recursion, casting

I want the result to be of Type String, so i tried to cast the recursive call with str function

When returning a result of Type int the function below works fine

```
def factor(n: int) -> int:
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return n * factor(n - 1)


print("factorial 5=", factor(5))
```

Output:

```
factorial 5= 120
```

But when casting the recursive call to str `str(n * factor(n - 1))`  i got a different result

```
def factor(n: int) -> str:
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return str(n * factor(n - 1))


print("factorial 5=", factor(5))
```

Output:

```
factorial 5= 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: because you make cast on all level not only at last return

Comment: The logic of `return n * factor(n - 1)` only makes sense if `factor(n - 1)` is an int, not a string. So you don't want the recursive calls to return strings.

Answer (score 1):

The recursion depends on being called recursively with an int argument. Therefore, you need a wrapper like

```
def factor(n: int) -> str:
    def factor_internal(n: int):
        if n <= 1:
            return 1
        return n*factor_internal(n - 1)
    
    return str(factor_internal(n))


print("factorial 5=", factor(5))
```

In your implementation, the multiplication `n*factor(n-1)` is a multiplication of an integer `n` with a string `factor(n-1)`. And in Python, this results in a concatenation of strings, `n`-times.